# Postgres serializable transactions not working as intended

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions

I have the following code (pseudocode, a mix of JavaScript and SQL) running inside a serializable transaction:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE

const missions = select * from missions
if (missions.length) == 0 {
  insert into missions values (blah)
}

COMMIT
```

In other words, I. am:

- Selecting all rows in the `missions` table
- Check if there are no rows (from my application code)
- Create a row if there were no rows.

Now, when I ran the code above in parallel (say 10 threads), I wound up seeing more than 1 rows being created.  Given I'm using a serializable transaction, shouldn't it be impossible for more than 1 row to be created?

I had since made the code into a single query like:

```
insert into missions
select * from possible-missions limit (1 - (select count(*) from missions))
```

Which works, but I still don't understand why my original code wasn't working as intended.

EDIT: I have created a repo for reproducing this issue: https://github.com/derekchiang/postgres-bug

Comment: Right, that is impossible with the `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level. You must have made a mistake somewhere. To make me believe otherwise, you'd have to come up with a reproducer.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: even if all rows are inserted with different PK values?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name For a sequential scan, you'd get a predicate lock on the whole relation.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Would the fact that I had a `WHERE` clause in the select change anything?  Instead of simply `select *`, it's actually predicated on a foreign key in my case.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I've created a repo that reproduces this issue: https://github.com/derekchiang/postgres-bug

Comment: Yes, that can make a difference, because then the two transactions might indeed be independent from each other.

Comment: It would be most interesting to know the SQL statements issued.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe it's these: https://pastebin.com/dEjDQJX4

Note that the third line is only executed if the application decides that the count is 0: https://github.com/derekchiang/postgres-bug/blob/master/test.js#L21

Comment: Actually, I rewrote the example with a different postgres driver and it worked, so I think it might be a bug in the driver I was using.  Closing this issue for now.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be an issue in the postgres driver I was using: it worked for `pg` and `pg-promise` but not `slonik` (the one I was using).

Comment: Yes, it cannot be connected to the SQL statements, because these will clearly conflict in PostgreSQL.

Comment: [Configurable Transactions](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#configurable-transactions) in `pg-promise` are easy to use, and well tested by time. If it doesn't work in other libraries, then the issue is in the library.